# Find the number of $x$ such that $\sigma_1(x)=n$, $n$ is a given positive integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\sigma_1(x)$ denotes the sum of the positive divisor of the integer $x$. $\sigma_1(x)=\sum_{d\mid x}d$.

For a positive integer $x=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i}$ we have $\sigma_1(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k\dfrac{p_i^{\alpha_{i}+1}-1}{p_i-1}$. Therefore, I considered enumerating all the possible $\dfrac{p_i^{\alpha_{i}+1}-1}{p_i-1}$ that can divide exactly $n$. I wrote a program that calculates $F(n,p_i)$ - the number of $x$ whose minimum prime factor is above $p_i$ - by recursion, and it works well when $n\le 10^{12}$. However it doesn't give me further knowledge about my problem, and I cannot figure out it's time complexity, either.

It seems that the answer is less than $\sqrt{n}$, but I have no idea to prove it. Does anyone know whether it's true or not? Or is there any efficient algorithm on this problem?

**Edit**
Let me explain it more clearly: now I want to deicide whether the number of solutions is less than $\sqrt{n}$ (or maybe $O(\sqrt{n})$). I believe it's true, but I cannot give a proof.

Comment: So you want an efficient method to determine the number of solutions $\sigma(m)=n$ , where $n$ is a given positive integer and $\sigma(m)$ the divisor-sum-functio, do I understand this right ?

Comment: @Peter yes, that's exactly what I need

Comment: Let's take $n=19160064000$ as an example, the number of solutions is $85349$, which is smaller than $\sqrt{n}=138419.9$

Answer (score 1):

Comment: I use some results in my answer to this question(question /3597960/equation $\sigma(n)=\sigma(n+1)$) by Peter. For example numbers $x=33, 35, 47$ have $\sigma(x)=48$ and we have $3<\sqrt {48}=6.9..$.  Another example $x=71, 46, 51, 55$ have $\sigma 72$. In this simple model we have:

$\sigma(x)=p+q+pq+1=(p+1)(q+1)\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$

For example for $\sigma(48)$ we have:

$48=(0+1)(47+1)$ which gives $(p, q)=(0, 47)$

$48= (3+1)(11+1)$, which gives $(p, q)=(3, 11)$

$48=(5+1)(7+1)$, which gives $(p, q)=(5, 7)$

That is for $\sigma(48)$ we have three numbers 33, 35 and 47.Or for $\sigma(72)$ we have four number. Clearly $3<\sqrt {48}=7.6...$ and $4<\sqrt{72}=8.4...$.

Now suppose we have a number like $x=48\times 72$, so the number of solutions for $\sigma(48\times 72=3456$ is at least $3\times 4=12$ . We probably can construct more than 12 equations like (1) from $3456$  and find more solutions. This could be the base for a simpler algorithm for finding number of solutions. Clearly a large number may be written as a product of numerous different factors their number of solution is already found and find number of all solutions.

Update: to answer your question in comment, we have to check all primes less than $3556/3=1152$, for example we can find:

$3456=(2+1)(1151+1)\Rightarrow x=2\times 1151=2302$

$3456=(3+1)(863+1)\Rightarrow x= 3\times 863=2589$

$3456=(7+1)(431+1) \Rightarrow x=7\times 431=3017$

Also $x=(17\times 191=3247),(23\times 143= 3289),(31\times 107=3317),(71\times 47= 3337)$

are some more solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain "We probably can construct more..." further? I'm not able to find a quick method.